# How to refresh messages pane in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I need to refresh Messages pane in SSMS more often, is there a way to achieve that without GO statements?

My query is:

```
 DECLARE @Deleted_Rows INT @Deleted_Rows = 1;
 DECLARE @Deleted_Rows_Total bigINT = 0;
 DECLARE @t1 DATETIME;
 DECLARE @t2 DATETIME;

 WHILE (@Deleted_Rows > 0)
   BEGIN
      SET @t1 = GETDATE();
      DELETE TOP (100000)  FROM  PenData WHERE Cas < '20200101'
      SET @Deleted_Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
      SET @t2 = GETDATE();

      SET @Deleted_Rows_Total = @Deleted_Rows_Total +@Deleted_Rows
      PRINT DATEDIFF(SECOND,@t1,@t2)
      PRINT @Deleted_Rows_Total

      --SELECT @Deleted_Rows AS smazano, @Deleted_Rows_Total AS celkem, DATEDIFF(SECOND,@t1,@t2) AS elapsed_s, GETDATE() as CAS
 END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RAISERROR ... WITH NOWAIT` can be used instead of (or in addition to) `PRINT` to cause SQL Server to send pending results immediately to the client.

The example below uses `RAISERROR ... WITH NOWAIT` with an empty string and zero severity to return the output of the preceding `PRINT` statements immediately.

```
WHILE (@Deleted_Rows > 0)
   BEGIN
      SET @t1 = GETDATE();
      DELETE TOP (100000)  FROM  PenData WHERE Cas < '20200101'
      SET @Deleted_Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
      SET @t2 = GETDATE();

      SET @Deleted_Rows_Total = @Deleted_Rows_Total +@Deleted_Rows
      PRINT DATEDIFF(SECOND,@t1,@t2)
      PRINT @Deleted_Rows_Total

      RAISERROR('', 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT; --flush message buffer immediately

      UPDATE dbo.MyLog
      SET CurrentStatus = CONCAT('Seconds:',DATEDIFF(SECOND,@t1,@t2), 'Deleted rows:', @Deleted_Rows_Total);
      WHERE Id = @logId

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer, but I've seen people work around this limitation of SSMS by updating row in dedicated table, where long running procedures reported their current state.

e. g. something like

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyLog(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CurrentStatus VARCHAR(4000)
);


DECLARE @Deleted_Rows INT @Deleted_Rows = 1;
DECLARE @Deleted_Rows_Total bigINT = 0;
DECLARE @t1 DATETIME;
DECLARE @t2 DATETIME;

INSERT INTO dbo.MyLog(CurrentStatus)
VALUES ('Start');

DECLARE @logId INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

WHILE (@Deleted_Rows > 0)
   BEGIN
      SET @t1 = GETDATE();
      DELETE TOP (100000)  FROM  PenData WHERE Cas < '20200101'
      SET @Deleted_Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
      SET @t2 = GETDATE();

      SET @Deleted_Rows_Total = @Deleted_Rows_Total +@Deleted_Rows
      PRINT DATEDIFF(SECOND,@t1,@t2)
      PRINT @Deleted_Rows_Total

      UPDATE dbo.MyLog
      SET CurrentStatus = CONCAT('Seconds:',DATEDIFF(SECOND,@t1,@t2), 'Deleted rows:', @Deleted_Rows_Total);
      WHERE Id = @logId

END
```